# How to create an exception instance from a java stacktrace string

Tags: java

I want to restore an exception instance from a stacktrace string (in java).
I need to parse the stacktrace(cause, message...) and thought it would be easier to do it through the exception api.
does anyone know if and how it can be done?

Comment: The `Exception` class does not have a string parser.  Why on earth would it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no general solution to this problem. Any `Throwable` class might have its own constructor parameters and internal logic, with no way to recreate an instance from text.

Exception classes aren't meant to be used this way. Depending on what you're trying to do, you are probably better off making an `ExceptionMessage` class representing your parsed data. You can't `throw` it, but you can have "`String message`" and "`List<String> stackTraceLines`" and whatnot.

If you absolutely need a literal `Exception` object, you can't do it with text alone. If you can change the origin so that it [serializes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) its exceptions instead of printing their stack traces, you can deserialize them on the other side instead of trying to parse it yourself.

But whatever approach you take is going to be error-prone. There's nothing that guarantees that `printStackTrace` has the exact structure you're expecting. There's nothing that guarantees that all `Throwable` instances are *actually* serializable, even though they're all marked that way.

Again, what you're describing really isn't the purpose of the printed stack trace. It's supposed to be an informal diagnostic tool for developers, not a structured data format.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.
I'm actually not really interested in having the exception instance but rather in its structure and api. 
guess I'll left with writing a "parser"...